# Where to find all camp sites available in an area or city?

Tags: online-resources, tips-and-tricks, camping, campers

As a traveler, sometimes I want to stay in a camp site, rather than in a hotel, motel or hostel. But sometimes it is very difficult to find this camp sites in the web.
Is there any website or app that show all the camp sites available in an area? For example: Camp sites in Yosemite National Park.
I acknowledge that there are federal websites but not a private one.

Comment: That's a bit too broad, care to narrow it down to an area in particular ?

Comment: I thought worldwide! But it would ok if something in Europe or USA

Comment: Have you tried using Google Maps - going to the area you want and searching for "camping" or "camp sites"?

Comment: Yes, and it works. But you have to try one by one, their own website (if they have any). I am looking something like booking.com  including campings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you will find something as universal as Trivago, Skyscanner, Kayak for campsites but your friendly neighborhood [Google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=campsite%20booking%20website) can yield some results that will let you book at least some of the sites online:

- [Reserve America](http://www.reserveamerica.com)
- [HipCamp](http://www.hipcamp.com)
- [Recreation.gov](http://www.recreation.gov) - For US National Park Service sites.

There is probably more but you should be able to find them on your own.

Answer (score 2):

This is super old, I know, but I came here looking for the same question. Several tabs (and years!) later, I found a few others:

- [Explorely](https://www.explorely.co) aggregates all of those listed earlier *and some of those below* - it's a bit like kayak.com for outdoor travel
- Campspot.com has what looks like a few thousand listings that are using their booking system
- Spot2Nite pulls in booking info and is a bit like Expedia (they are also appearing on Reserve America)
- The Dyrt is pulling in a bunch of different sites and has their own listings as well

Comment: Nice. Do you know if Explorely is USA-only? It says "Our vision is to help every traveller to explore the world", but every non-USA location I've tried so far just says "Ooops! No results found"

Comment: Ahhh, it looks like it Explorely is very new and in a beta state currently. The [blog](https://www.splitmedia.ca/blog/) is full of placeholders, Instagram link goes nowhere, there's a lot of UI bugs (inconsistent filter state between the sidebar and header bars, sidebar overhangs the footer, there's HTML error content in blog post URLs...), and if I try a very popular non-US location like Lake Bled, I get a number like "6 results" in the top header but the "Ooops! No results found" on the main content. Hopefully they can get it all working 

Comment: I'm in the US so it worked for me. I guess it isn't really like a true Kayak.com. I know there is Campsited.com in Europe, but I don't know if they have results in Slovenia. It looks like it might be more Western Europe.